# CloudFront URL signature works fine for RTMP, why won't it work for download URL?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, rtmp, amazon-cloudfront

I've written a PHP script that generates a signed CloudFront URL for RTMP with use in Flowplayer that's working just fine, but when I use the same signature generation method to create a download URL I get an AccessDenied XML file from Amazon.  I've tried just about everything and I'm at my wits end.  Anyone know why the signature would work for RTMP streaming, but that same signature generation method would fail for a download?

```
$keyPairId = 'APK...';
$privateKey = '/var/www/certs/pk-APK....pem';
$rtmp = false; 
$distribution = 'd2m...';

// Get extension.
$extension = substr($this->getFilename(), strrpos($this->getFilename(), '.') + 1);
$fileName = substr($this->getFilename(), 0, strrpos($this->getFilename(), '.'));

$expires = strtotime(gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+3 hours')));
$json = '{"Statement":[{"Resource":"' . $fileName . '","Condition"{"DateLessThan":{"AWS:EpochTime":' . $expires . '}}}]}';

// read cloudfront private key pair
$fp = fopen($privateKey, 'r');
$priv_key = fread($fp, 8192);
fclose($fp);

// create the private key
$key = openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);

// sign the policy with the private key
// depending on your php version you might have to use
// openssl_sign($json, $signed_policy, $key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1)
openssl_sign($json, $signed_policy, $key);

openssl_free_key($key);

// create url safe signed policy
$base64_signed_policy = base64_encode($signed_policy);
$signature = str_replace(array('+', '=', '/'), array('-', '_', '~'),                 $base64_signed_policy);

// construct the url
$urlParams = urlencode($this->getFilename()) . '?Expires=' . $expires .'&Signature=' . $signature . '&Key-Pair-Id=' . $keyPairId;
$keyPairId;
if ($rtmp) {
    $url = ( ($this->getExtension() != 'flv') ? $this->getExtension() . ':' : '' ) . $urlParams;
} else {
    $url = 'https://' . $distribution . '.cloudfront.net/' . $urlParams;
}
```

Comment: This might or might not be helpful: I think there is a `:` missing in the line starting with `$json = ...` between the key `"Condition"` and its value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, signed RTMP urls are [made differently](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-creating-signed-url-custom-policy.html) than regular urls

> RTMP distributions: Include only the stream name. For example, if the
>   full URL for a streaming video is:
>
> rtmp://s5c39gqb8ow64r.cloudfront.net/videos/mp3_name.mp3
>
> then use the following value for Resource:
>
> videos/mp3_name

Regular signed urls contain the entire path.

Secondly, cloudfront RTMP distributions only distribute streaming media over RTMP. You said that you wanted a download url, so using an RTMP distribution will not enable you to download the file.

You probably want to create a cloudfront web distribution and link it to the same bucket, then generate a signed url using the web distribution, and access it that way.